# Changing a method of an instance from another class in java

Tags: java, methods

Im trying to change the method of just one instance from another class. Is this possible, and if so how can I do it?

Im trying to rewrite the entire method durring runtime. I only want the method to be changed for one instance of the class, and all the other instance's methods should stay the same. I hope that clears up some confusion

Comment: What do you mean by changing? Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: Do you mean to change the implementation of a method? Of an instance, i.e. an object in memory?

Comment: What do you mean change the method of just one instance? Can u be more descriptive?

Comment: You might be able to accomplish this with [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible.

Method definitions are stored by class, not instance (and are immutable anyway). One thing you can do is to store a callable object per instance and call that.

Comment: Ahh.. too bad. Thanks though, I think I will do what you suggested

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide more details and perhaps some sample code to get a sufficient answer. That being said, if class Foo extends class Bar, class Foo can override a method of class Bar. Is that what you're trying to do?